# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.

Tags: c#, smtp, mail-server

I am creating a form using "createuserwizard" in asp.This is my code.

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="userwizard" ContinueDestinationPageUrl="~/secretfiles/secret.aspx" runat="server" >
    <MailDefinition BodyFileName="register.txt" Subject="Registration Confirmation" From="amrit.enest@gmail.com" />
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

This is my web.config file settings.

```
 <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="amrit.enest@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="amrit.enest@gmail.com" password="sending emails's password" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

Then settled up a Smtp .in ISS settings i selected following options.

```
->Use localhost(SMTP)
->port=25
->authentication not required
```

Now when a new user click submit button ,it gives following error message and mail is not being send.

**The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ud8sm21095949igb.4**

Please help guys.

Comment: Well either your password is not correct or you could, I don't know - use secure smtp port 465

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `enableSsl="true"`, like this:

```
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="amrit.enest@gmail.com">
    <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="amrit.enest@gmail.com" password="sending emails's password" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

The server requires SSL, so you need to add this to your config:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="amrit.enest@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" userName="amrit.enest@gmail.com" 
        password="sending emails's password" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164242.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks.its working now. Just help to understand this code now.I assume it work in the following flow. localhost request the smtp.gmail.com(Server) with the sending email(Username,password),receiving email address to the send the mail to destination.Am i right? please let me know also this is a port number of my pc or smtp.gmail.com? Again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("your mail address@mail.com");
    SmtpClient clientobj = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    mail.From = from;
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(" to mail address@gmail.com"));
    mail.Subject = "example gridview";
    mail.Body+="Please check below data <br/><br/>";
    mail.Body += getgridviewdata(gv1);
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    clientobj.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your mailaddress@gmail.com", "your email password");
    clientobj.Port =587;
    clientobj.EnableSsl = true;
  clientobj.Send(mail);


}
```

in the above gv1 is my gridview id

```
public string getgridviewdata(GridView gv)
{
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder);
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    return strBuilder.ToString();
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}
```

you write the following also in source code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="example.aspx.cs" Inherits="example" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

Comment: please take care of proper code formatting next time around: click the question mark and then _advanced formating_ to learn how-to:-)